# Read values of specific column referenced by name of txt file using C++

Tags: c++, text, file-io, ofstream

Fristly I tried to read data referenced by specific column in a text file using c++ under eclipse, the text file is like that :

```
ProductA  ProductB  ProductC
23.3      39        45.2
33        32        ....
10.3      12.3      ....
....      ....      ....
```

Following a tutorial I writed a small program :

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

int rowA = 0;
int colA = 0;

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string LineA;
    int x;
    int arrayA[10][10] = {{0}};
    string filename;
    ifstream fileIN;

    fileIN.open("input.txt");

    if (fileIN.fail()) {
        cerr << "These File Can't Be Opened" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    cout << "\n" << endl;

    while (fileIN.good()) {
        while (getline(fileIN, LineA)) {
            istringstream streamA(LineA);
            colA = 0;

            while (streamA >> x) {
                arrayA[rowA][colA] = x;
                colA++;
            }

            rowA++;
        }
    }

    cout << "Rows :" << rowA << endl;
    cout << "Columns :" << colA << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < rowA; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < colA; j++) {
            cout << left << setw(6) << arrayA[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I hope to develop the code to read data of a specific column referenced by name then store values of a clumn in setter method instead of array so something like that:

```
 if(Name="ProductA") {
   // get values of this column and set it in a setter mothod                    
   //SetProductA(values here...!)
   // So I can set values of every column in her setter method of product
  }
```

Any Idea?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are using C-style arrays and not vectors?

Comment: @atru No I have no problem to use vectors, the big problem I have is that i must use setter method of name of specific column to set values as I explained above...

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context? You can store each column separately in a vector or a vector of vectors. But it seems you may be aiming for something broader.

Comment: What do you mean _I must use setter method of name of specific column to set values_ you have all your values in the text file already don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in your example file you've got some floating point values listed for the products, so an array of `int` is *not* what you want to be using! 
 Instead, I would recommend using a `vector` of `float` for each column of your data file.  This has two advantages.

1. It can store the correct values you read in from the file as `float`
2. You don't have to worry about blowing through your 10x10 fixed array

If the columns have more significance than the rows do (you want to store all product values from the same column together in the same container) then you can do something like this.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream infile("input.txt");
    if (infile.is_open())
    {
        std::string line;
        std::getline(infile, line);  // skip first line

        std::vector<float> productA;
        std::vector<float> productB;
        std::vector<float> productC;

        while (std::getline(infile, line))
        {
            float temp;
            std::stringstream ss(line);

            ss >> temp; // column A
            productA.push_back(temp);

            ss >> temp; // column B
            productB.push_back(temp);

            ss >> temp; // column C
            productC.push_back(temp);
        }
        // your product vectors are now populated and you can
        // do whatever you need with the column data here
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, so I'm following your code and it's works fine what I need more validation of data of every column before I use it with vector, I mean I should check data is empty of specific column before using store it in a vector?

Comment: How about excepting the answer? To be fair it has as much input validation as your original question. Did you try corrupting the input file and see what happens?

Comment: No, I use php to much so I'm not too much comfortable with c++, what I try to say is getting the code more clear and pure, I want to check if a float value of a column is empty so I get a message error before store it in a vector that's all..

Comment: @Nll Sanitization of inputs was not the question you asked. Please accept my answer if it works for you, then ask a new question about how you can sanitize your inputs from your file.